# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php        
    include_once("config.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM image,tags WHERE image_id=fk_image_id  ORDER BY creation_dt DESC LIMIT 5 ");
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tagname=$res['tag_txt'];
        $cols = implode(',','array_keys($tagname)');
        echo $cols;
        echo "<tr>"."<img  src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$res['path_txt']."' width='380' height='280' style='padding: 10px;'  />"."</tr>";            
    }        
?>
```

this is my code.error in passing arguments,is this implode function is correct?
i was using insert query for  explode function

Comment: remove single quotes around the second parameter

Comment: its fine, but strings are displayed seperately !!!
i want display the foreign key strings into a single string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try Updated code

```
    include_once("config.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT path_txt,GROUP_CONCAT(tag_txt SEPARATOR ', ') as image_tag FROM image,tags WHERE image_id=fk_image_id GROUP BY path_txt ORDER BY creation_dt DESC LIMIT 5");

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $tagname = $res['image_tag'];
        echo $tagname;
        echo "<tr>"."<img  src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$res['path_txt']."' width='380' height='280' style='padding: 10px;'  />"."</tr>";
    }//end of while loop
```

Comment: in your code you have passed string instead of array implode function need array as second parameter, single or double quotes shows result in string. So you have to pass array not string to implode function refer this explanation http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: its fine, but strings are displayed seperately !!!
i want display the foreign key strings into a single string.

Comment: before while declare $i=0;in your while loop you mentioned $tagname=$res['tag_txt']; this is a single string value so you have to consider it as array like this $tagname[$i]=$res['tag_txt']; and increament $i++; after end of while loop  $cols = implode(',',$tagname);

Comment: @sunilwananje Edit your answer and add those points that you have added as comments. That can make your answer meaningful.

Comment: #sunilwananje please paste your code and define properly.

Comment: @sunilwananje 
the above code is displaying strings into combine strings but the same images are repeated based on given strings.

in insert query for single image we are giving more strings,
in select query for same single image and strings should be displayed

Comment: @Prasanna Sorry am not getting, what you want to say exactly?

Comment: @sunilwananje  i have two tables one is primary key table(table name:image) another one is foreign key table(table name:tags).i gave input values for one image (upload file) and tag names(its give for multiple name ex; a,b).
if i give two tagname ex: a,b and image file is single.
the query executed sucessfully.but i want displaying that one single image and my tagnames(a,b).
 your code displaying was  tagnames(a)+image,then next tagname(b)  +image .
the foreign key id  rows saved in 65-a 65-b.   display the 65 id in one single tags.

Comment: you can try this query SELECT path_txt, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_txt SEPARATOR ', ') FROM image,tags WHERE image_id=fk_image_id GROUP BY path_txt ORDER BY creation_dt DESC LIMIT 5 it will give you your result

Comment: @sunilwananje    i got this error?
Notice: Undefined index: tag_txt in C:\xamppp\htdocs\memes\sample.php on line 33

Comment: i used your existing query parameter i just made little changes can you share your code

Comment: @sunilwananje   
please refer above code,...i have  edited in your post code

Comment: include_once("config.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT path_txt, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_txt SEPARATOR ',') FROM image,tags WHERE image_id=fk_image_id GROUP BY path_txt ORDER BY creation_dt DESC LIMIT 5 ");
    $tagname='';
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $tagname.=$res['tag_txt'].','; //concating $res['tag_txt'] with comma
        echo "<tr>"."<img  src='http://localhost:8080/memes/".$res['path_txt']."' width='380' height='280' style='padding: 10px;'  />"."</tr>";
    }
   $cols = substr($tagname,0,-1); 
   echo $cols;

Comment: @sunilwananje im also so happy,because three days i was try this logic. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121586/discussion-between-prasanna-and-sunilwananje).

Answer (score 0):

```
implode — Join array elements with a string

array_keys — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

Example :

$array = array("1" => "PHP code tester",  
              "foo" => "bar",
               5 => 89009, 
              "case" => "Random Stuff",
              "PHP Version" => phpversion()
              );

$arrayKey = implode(',',array_keys($array));

echo $arrayKey;

output will be : 1,foo,5,case,PHP Version

But you give a string parameter in this line

$cols = implode(',','array_keys($tagname)');

So you get warning : implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

actually this line will be :

$cols = implode(',',array_keys($tagname));
```